# How to get string back in c# after converting to binary in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, encoding, binary, ascii

I have string value key:

```
TxtProductKey.Text has value "key"
```

Encode this value

```
 byte[] Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TxtProductKey.Text.Trim());
```

Save it in database table in a column of datatype `binary(50) null`.

The value in the table looks like this:

```
0x6B00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Now I am trying to get it back in string value that I entered is `Key`

```
byte [] TempKey = (byte[])LicenseInfo.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ProductKey"];
var newText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(TempKey);
```

but the result I am getting in `newText` is:

```
k\0\0\0\0\0\00\
```

Where am I doing something wrong? I hope for your suggestions

C# code for saving value in database:

```
Sqlconnection.Open();

SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("SpAddAttempts", Sqlconnection);
Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Attempts", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Attempt;
Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Activate", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Activate;
Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Key", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = Key;

Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
CloseConnection();
```

Stored procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SpAddAttempts]
    @Attempts INT,
    @Activate BIT,
    @Key BINARY
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE License 
    SET Attempts = @Attempts,
        Activate = @Activate,
        ProductKey = @Key 
    WHERE LicenseId = '1'
END
```

Comment: You are not saving it right. The data has only one non-zero byte, it should have three bytes (i.e. `0x6B657900...`)

Comment: You can do that, can you see in debug what is the value of the Key byte array ? Before it goes inside the DB. The example shows only one character in the db binary data

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Can you show me mistake ? my saving code is there in my post.

Comment: @john The edit to the answer of Caius Jard (passing length) should fix this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can: you only stored a single byte (the equivalent of char `k`) in your db table.. 0x68 is `k`, the next byte is 0x00 - ascii null - string terminator - whatever your language of choice will refer to it as, it's definitely not `e`

So, because only the first byte has been preserved and the rest is ascii NUL 000000000000000000000000....), there's no way to know whether the rest of the value was `ey`, `eyboard`, `oolaid` etc.. The fault is during the storing of the value in the table (you didn't show code for that part) - it's only stored the first byte

I recommend you store this text as text, not binary; it seems like an unnecessary world of pain to store it as binary when it starts life as text and you clearly want it back out as text.

EDIT: Now you've posted the code that does the saving, I can see youve declared the parameter as type Binary, but you havent specified a length, so the length is defaulting to 1 byte. This is why only one of your bytes is getting saved. You need to declare the parameter more like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Key", SqlDbType.Binary, binaryData.Length); //dont pass an array longer than what the table can store, or you'll get a "data would be truncated" error
```

Comment: i enter "key" for saving and reason for encoding is to secure it otherwise it is easy to save text directly. May be i am doing any mistake so that it is saving only "k" value out of "key".

Comment: Oh yeah, converting it to binary makes it really secure when it's a couple of extra key strokes to paste it into https://www.branah.com/ascii-converter and get the original ascii back. ROT13'd text would be harder to crack (read: take a few seconds longer to realise that was the security mechanism). Either implement a proper security solution, or store it as text and review your "who has the sql server password" policy :)

Comment: bro you seems to be more professional i am quit new so dont have much information but thanks for giving me more information :) i edited post now you can find code for storing data.

Comment: If you're looking to store this data securely, you need to look at making it a lot harder to casually observe - encrypt it using a proper algorithm

Comment: i mention length of binary column @Key binary(50) in stored procedure help me out.